# android.view.WindowLeaked

Tags: android

```
inviteBu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(ChoiceList.size()>0)
             {

                    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MobileConnectActivity.this);
                    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.invite_dialog, null);
                    final EditText et =(EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.usercontent_edit);

                   dia= new AlertDialog.Builder(MobileConnectActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.invite_input_content))
                        .setView(textEntryView)
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.invite_send), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                 if(et.getText().toString()==null && et.getText().equals("") )
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.invite_content_check), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                 else{


                                     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

                                         CustomDialog mProgressBar = new CustomDialog(MobileConnectActivity.this, R.style.dialog);

                                        protected void onPreExecute() {

                                            mProgressBar.show();
                                        };

                                        protected void onCancelled() {
                                            mProgressBar.hide();
                                        };

                                        @Override
                                        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                                                ChoiceList=removeDuplicateList(ChoiceList);
                                                for(int i=0;i<ChoiceList.size();i++)
                                                {
                                                    Log.i("aaa",""+ChoiceList.get(i));
                                                    sendSMS(ChoiceList.get(i), et.getText().toString());
                                                }
                                            return "OK";
                                        }

                                        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                                            mProgressBar.hide();

                                            if (response != null ) {

                                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.invite_succeed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                                                    intent.setClass(MobileConnectActivity.this, inviteMainActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);

                                                MobileConnectActivity.this.finish();
                                            } else {
                                                //mHelper.showResponseErrorMessage(response);
                                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                                intent.setClass(MobileConnectActivity.this, inviteMainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                        };

                                    }.execute();

                                 }

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.invite_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                                /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                            }
                        }).show();

             }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.invite_choice_check), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

it give me :

```
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240): Activity com.portaura.myaura.invite.MobileConnectActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405c32d0 that was originally added here
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.portaura.myaura.invite.MobileConnectActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405c32d0 that was originally added here
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:266)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:174)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at com.portaura.myaura.invite.MobileConnectActivity$3$1$1.onPreExecute(MobileConnectActivity.java:161)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at com.portaura.myaura.invite.MobileConnectActivity$3$1.onClick(MobileConnectActivity.java:201)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:165)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 03:36:24.519: E/WindowManager(23240):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Answer (score 100):

Window leaked exceptions are usually caused by dialogs which are not dismissed properly.
ie if you are planning to dismiss a dialog in Onpostexecute of asynctask and the activity that created it  has ended it will throw a  window leak. Make sure you dimisss dialog in onPause of the activity.

Comment: @pengwang Is this not the answer?

Comment: For others with this error: Also make sure to look for errors above this error. An app crashing while the dialog is open will cause this error after the actual error that crashed the app.

Comment: Do these exceptions cause an app to crash?

Comment: So does the dialog stay open forever if I never dismiss it? I have a similar error with a "loading" dialog, but if I dismiss the dialog then it never actually appears on the screen.

Answer (score 15):

Whenever you initiate a ProgressDialog, that should be dismissed properly after the background task gets done, or even cancellation of the background running task. So,

instead of `mProgressBar.hide();` use `mProgressBar.dismiss();`

you will not get android.view.WindowLeaked error

hope this helps

Answer (score 11):

Check if you are using finish() function before the mDialog.show() function. If it is remove the finish() and add it after the show().

Answer (score 7):

whren you miss this code : `mProgressDialog.dismis();` that time may be you will receive this type of error.

Answer (score 5):

Another scenario where this error occurs is when the app crushes while a dialog is shown. Look above this error for additional errors.

Answer (score 5):

In `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` callback, dismiss the dialog using `dialogName.dismiss();`

Also do a null check. That is:

```
if (dialogName != null) {
    dialogName.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is **AsyncTask**.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

    CustomDialog mProgressBar = new CustomDialog(MobileConnectActivity.this, R.style.dialog);
    .... 
}
```

You create a progress bar inside async task which makes a problem when you move to another activity.

For this before dismiss or show()

```
if(!isFinishing() && dialog != null) { dialog.dismiss();}
```

Usage of **isFinishing()**

```
 * Check to see whether this activity is in the process of finishing,
 * either because you called {@link #finish} on it or someone else
 * has requested that it finished.  This is often used in
 * {@link #onPause} to determine whether the activity is simply pausing or
 * completely finishing.
 *
 * @return If the activity is finishing, returns true; else returns false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply dismissing the dialog was not enough to get rid of the error for me. It turns out my code was holding onto a reference to the dialog even after it was dismissed. The key for me was to set that reference to null after dismissing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was happening because I used the `android:noHistory="true"` for the activity that was causing the problem, and it only happened on Android 6.0 API 23.