# Payumoney payment gateway issue after filling all card information

Tags: android, kotlin, integration, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am getting issues when I am integration with payment gateway here is my code :

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)


    // Result Code is -1 send from Payumoney activity
    Log.d("MainActivity", "request code $requestCode resultcode $resultCode")
    if (requestCode == PayUmoneyFlowManager.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val transactionResponse = data.getParcelableExtra<TransactionResponse>(PayUmoneyFlowManager
            .INTENT_EXTRA_TRANSACTION_RESPONSE)

        val resultModel = data.getParcelableExtra<ResultModel>(PayUmoneyFlowManager.ARG_RESULT)

        if (transactionResponse != null && transactionResponse.getPayuResponse() != null) {
            if (transactionResponse.transactionStatus == TransactionResponse.TransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL) {
                val payuResponse = transactionResponse.getPayuResponse()
                var gson: Gson = Gson()
                var response = gson.fromJson(payuResponse, PayumoneyResponse::class.java)
                Log.e("@@Response", response.toString())
                addoinsApi(response.result.amount)
            } else {
            }


        } else if (resultModel != null && resultModel.error != null) {
            Log.d(Membership.TAG, "Error response : " + resultModel.error.transactionResponse)
        } else {
            Log.d(Membership.TAG, "Both objects are null!")
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting Error like this

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.payumoney.core.SdkWebViewActivityNew has leaked window DecorView@9588e25[SdkWebViewActivityNew] that was originally added here
```

please help me Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably something related with a missing dismiss on a dialog. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590382/android-view-windowleaked#answer-14143902

Comment: I did not get this